# Int32.Min vs Int32.MinMagnitude

Tags: c#, integer, numbers, .net-7.0, .net-generic-math

What is the difference between the static methods [`Int32.Min`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.min) and [`Int32.MinMagnitude`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.minmagnitude), that were introduced in .NET 7? Their signature and description is the same:

```
// Compares two values to compute which is lesser.
public static int Min (int x, int y);

// Compares two values to compute which is lesser.
public static int MinMagnitude (int x, int y);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MinMagnitude()` compares the *absolute values* of the inputs. When `x` and `y` are positive, it works exactly like `Min()`. If either or both of them are negative then the sign(s) will be ignored for the comparison, but are kept on the return value.

Some examples:

```cs
Debug.Assert(int.MinMagnitude( 10,  1) ==  1);
Debug.Assert(int.MinMagnitude(-10,  1) ==  1);
Debug.Assert(int.MinMagnitude( 10, -1) == -1);
Debug.Assert(int.MinMagnitude(-10, -1) == -1);
```

One special case is when comparing numbers of equal absolute value, but different sign. Then it returns the negative of the common absolute value:

```cs
Debug.Assert(int.MinMagnitude(-1,  1) == -1);
Debug.Assert(int.MinMagnitude( 1, -1) == -1);
```

Have a look at the source code [here](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Int32.cs,892).

Comment: I would argue adding [source code](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Int32.cs,892) for one of implementation can improve the answer a bit =)

Comment: @TheodorZoulias it is almost (if we imagine such method) `int.MinByAbs(x, y)` =)

Comment: @TheodorZoulias it selects number which has minimal absolute value=)

Comment: @GuruStron I think the `-1,1` example covers those cases already, but I added `1,-1` as well.

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride sorry, missed those.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the implementation for [`Int32`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Int32.cs,892):

```
  public static int MinMagnitude(int x, int y)
  {
        int absX = x;

        if (absX < 0)
        {
            absX = -absX;

            if (absX < 0)
            {
                return y;
            }
        }

        int absY = y;

        if (absY < 0)
        {
            absY = -absY;

            if (absY < 0)
            {
                return x;
            }
        }

        if (absX < absY)
        {
            return x;
        } 
        if (absX == absY)
        {
            return IsNegative(x) ? x : y;
        }
        return y;
  }
```

This method returns number with minimal absolute value, i.e. magnitude (if equal - the negative of the two preferred).

**UPD**

I can't get access to  IEEE 754 2019 where `minimumMagnitude` is defined, but from [the PDF on "The Removal/Demotion of MinNum and MaxNum Operations from IEEE 754™-2018"](https://grouper.ieee.org/groups/msc/ANSI_IEEE-Std-754-2019/background/minNum_maxNum_Removal_Demotion_v3.pdf), the original `minNumMag` was defined as:

> **minNumMag(x, y)** is the canonicalized number `x if | x| < | y|`, `y if | y| < | x|`, otherwise `minNum(x,y)`.

As the doc states - reason for removal was non-associativity for `NaN` handling which, I understand is "fixed" in the new standard.

For this the `double` implementation can give mode detail, I think:

```cs
public static double MinMagnitude(double x, double y)
{
    // This matches the IEEE 754:2019 `minimumMagnitude` function
    //
    // It propagates NaN inputs back to the caller and
    // otherwise returns the input with a lesser magnitude.
    // It treats +0 as lesser than -0 as per the specification.
 
    double ax = Abs(x);
    double ay = Abs(y);
 
    if ((ax < ay) || double.IsNaN(ax))
    {
        return x;
    }
 
    if (ax == ay)
    {
        return double.IsNegative(x) ? x : y;
    }
 
    return y;
}
```

Comment: Guru Stron I removed my outdated comments to keep the answer clean. Btw, although your answer is more scientific, I accepted @GoodNightNerdPride's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74429063/11178549) because it offers a more practical explanation of the difference IMHO.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Yes, NP =) I've added my answer case original version of GoodNightNerdPride's one was not fully correct in terms of explanation.

Answer (score 0):

It's a method on the newly-introduced interface `INumberBase<TSelf>`, and is [documented as](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.inumberbase-1.minmagnitude?view=net-7.0#system-numerics-inumberbase-1-minmagnitude(-0-0)):

> Compares two values to compute which is lesser.

And has the remark:

> For `IFloatingPointIeee754<TSelf>` this method matches the IEEE 754:2019 minimumMagnitude function. This requires NaN inputs to be propagated back to the caller and for -0.0 to be treated as less than +0.0.

So that remark would proves the documentation of the method to be wrong, as it returns the value with the lesser *magnitude*, being the compared absolute values.

So if you want absolute comparisons, or if you do floating point math and want NaN or positive/negative zero comparisons as described, then use `MinMagnitude()` instead of `Min()`.

Comment: *"...if you do floating point math..."* -- To be honest I am interested exclusively about the difference between `Min` and `MinMagnitude` in the context of 32-bit integers. AFAIK floating point math are not applicable to integers.

Comment: Yeah but it's an interface that's applied to all built-in numeric types, and there were more parts to that sentence.

Comment: Removing the parts that I am not interested for: *"So if you want absolute comparisons then use `MinMagnitude()` instead of `Min()`."* -- Honestly if I want to compare the absolute values I will do `int.Abs(x).CompareTo(int.Abs(y));`. The semantics of the `MinMagnitude` method for integers seems to be a mess.

Comment: They aren't clear to me either, but I'm not a mathematician nor well-versed in floating point math. I think we can agree the documentation is lacking.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I think this method is just a byproduct of [the generic math APIs](https://github.com/dotnet/designs/pull/205), and should not be used in general. You may notice the strange comparison in the source (`if (absX < 0)` inside another `if (absX < 0)`) which is used to check `NaN` (`f != f`) for a floating number.

Comment: @shingo I am tempted to self-answer my question, with something like: *"The `Int32.Min` is a method equivalent with the `Math.Min`, that does what you expect it to do. The `Int32.MinMagnitude` is an abomination that you should forget about it. The more that you try to understand it, the more brain cells that are dying in your head."* 

Comment: It's about consistency in the overall implementation of the interfaces. With Int32, it resolves in the minimum absolute member, which also resolves `MinMagnitudeNumber`, different in floating point values. The implementation may seem inconsistent because Int32 has no NaN and if you test `float.MinMagnitude(-0.0f, +0.0f)`, with `float.IsNegative(float.MinMagnitude(-0.0f, +0.0f))` you get `true`, while `int.IsNegative(int.MinMagnitude(-0, +0))` you get `false`. How would you implement the `INumberBase` interface, in relation to IntX?

Comment: @Jimi I would implement it with a big fat `throw new NotSupportedException()`.

Comment: Well, it actually appears to be supported. Would you use Math.Min + Math.Abs instead? That's using a different paradigm and *may* be subject to two's complement exceptions. .Net 7 targets a much *wider audience*, hence the use of wider documented standards

Comment: @Jimi fair enough. Apparently I am not part of the target audience of the `Int32.MinMagnitude` API. I am OK with this.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I clearly forgot to mention what that *different paradigm* is, in practice. Now that interfaces have all those `static abstract` Properties / Methods, you can use derived `INumberBase<TSelf>` interfaces in generics, specifically `INumber<T>`, so you can write, e.g., `T Operations<T>(IEnumerable<T> numbers) where T : INumber<T> { T value = T.Zero; /* operations */ return value; }`. You can pass a collection of Int32 or Double etc. numbers to the method. It should be more clear why I said *It's about consistency in the overall implementation of the interfaces*